# ECK Drupal Module + Commerce Marketplace Entity Error

Tags: php, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce with inStock Premium Theme. Everything was going well until Client asked for a Multi Sellers Features. So, I turn on Drupal Commerce Marketplace Module and now, it's is happening like this.
[image]
[image]
[image]

According to the searching on Google, I found on the problem was with ECK Module. So, I download the latest version. But still not OK.

Comment: consider putting this question on drupal.stackexchange.com  you will get more attention there. :)

Comment: I saw similar question there, without answer :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest market place module, then I think the latest ECK is not compatible with this. From my experience ECK : version = "7.x-2.0-rc2" is compatible with 
Commerce Marketplace : version = "7.x-1.0-beta2".

Comment: I am also having the same problem , updated to lasted Development Version but still same problem